# Why are my Cucumber Rake Tasks executing even though I did not ask them to?

Tags: cucumber, rake, jruby

I'm struggling with understanding how Rake processes Cucumber tasks.  I'm probably doing this wrong, but can't see what the "right" way is.

I've got the following tasks:

```
namespace :features do

  Cucumber::Rake::Task.new(:browser, 'Run Cucumber Features using a Browser') do |t|
    t.profile = ENV['HUDSON'] ? 'browser_hudson' : 'browser' 
    setup_environment
    check_profile(t.profile)
  end

  Cucumber::Rake::Task.new(:headless, 'Run Cucumber Features using a Headless Browser') do |t|
    t.profile = ENV['HUDSON'] ? 'hudson' : 'default' 
    setup_environment
    check_profile(t.profile)
  end
end
```

This seems straight forward to me.

The problem is when I run any of the cucumber tasks, I'm seeing both tasks execute.  So if I do:

```
rake features:browser
```

or

```
rake features:headless
```

I see setup_environment and check_profile run twice, and then the actual task getting invoked. I end up seeing something like this:

```
setup_environment called
check_profile called, running in browser
setup_environment called
check_profile called, running headless
** Invoke features:browser (first_time)
** Execute features:browser
```

And of course, it's now running headless.

I'm guessing I shouldn't be doing any "work" inside the task definition for a Cucumber task.  Is there an alternative I should be looking into to accomplish this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by doing the following:

```
task :browser => ['features:setupenv', 'features:isbrowser', 'features:browser'] do
end

task :headless => ['features:setupenv', 'features:headless'] do
end
```

The two new features tasks are:

```
task :setupenv do
  setup_environment
end

task :isbrowser do
  ENV['BROWSER'] ||= 'true'
end
```

This works, but still doesn't answer the question why Cucumber tasks operate differently from standard Rake tasks.  I guess it's a bad assumption on my part that Cucumber rake tasks extended a standard Rake task, when what's really happening is a Rake Task is being constructed dynamically.  In order for that to happen, the code needs to execute, rather than act as a pointer to that code for execution later (which is what I assumed would happen)